# Objectbox Sync Server Configuration Troubleshooting

Tags: objectbox, flutter-objectbox, objectbox-android

Follow guide from https://sync.objectbox.io/objectbox-sync-server

I already has my downloaded Objectbox sync server files

1. Download My Objectbox sync-server file (i got it from Objectbox Team) that and extract it
2. Copy my objectbox-model.json (generated file from my flutter app) to the extracted folder
3. 

try with

```
     ./sync-server --model=objectbox-model.json --unsecure-no-authentication
```

It gave me

```
     001-16:08:29.6169 [INFO ] [SySvAp] Starting ObjectBox Sync Server version 2 
     (protocol version: 3, core: 2.9.2-2021-07-19 (SyncServer, admin, tree, dlog))
     error parsing options: Option ‘unsecure-no-authentication’ does not exist
```

4. Create configuration file (sync-server-config.js)
   Contain:

   ```
    {
     "dbDirectory": "objectbox",
     "dbMaxSize": "100G",
     "modelFile": "objectbox-model.json",
     "bind": "ws://0.0.0.0:9999",
     "browserBind": "http://127.0.0.1:9980",
     "browserThreads": 4,
     "certificatePath": "",
     "auth": {
     "sharedSecret": "<secret>",
     }
    }
   ```
5. And Open Terminal on from that  folder Run ./sync-server
6. It return me Error

   ```
     001-16:35:51.9701 [INFO ] [SySvAp] Starting ObjectBox Sync Server version 2 
     (protocol version: 3, core: 2.9.2-2021-07-19 (SyncServer, admin, tree, dlog))
     001-16:35:51.9702 [INFO ] [SySvAp] Loading configuration file sync-server- 
     config.js
     Error loading configuration file sync-server-config.js - Invalid JSON at 283 - 
     Missing a name for object member..
   ```

I did try with

```
     certificatePath": "",
```

removed, also give the same error

I am new to Objectbox and I want to try with the Sync Part,

your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This was actually a typo in our docs, thanks for reporting! The option to use no authentication for development is called --unsecured-no-authentication (note the d in unsecured). Note that you can use --help to show available options (https://sync.objectbox.io/objectbox-sync-server#configuration).

Comment: Thank you, Uwe - ObjectBox, it works now

Comment: Great! Added this as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to use no authentication for development is called `--unsecured-no-authentication` (note the d in unsecured). (This was actually a typo in our docs.)

Note that you can use `--help` to show available options (https://sync.objectbox.io/objectbox-sync-server#configuration).

Comment: I am able to access to the ObjectBox Browser and test input data from flutter app android emulator